# Invalid query. You cannot use more than one 'in' filter

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
this.ref.collection("users", ref => ref.where("uid1","in", [reciverId, senderId])
        .where("uid2","in", [reciverId, senderId]))
```

give me error like

> "Invalid query. You cannot use more than one 'in' filter"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

Since the release of the Firebase JS SDK Version 9.18.0 on March 16, 2023 it is possible to combine several `in` clauses in a Query.

However note that "Cloud Firestore limits a query to a maximum of **30 disjunctions** in disjunctive normal form", as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limits_on_or_queries) (which includes examples on the number of disjunctions for different types of queries)

---

#### OLD ANSWER:

This is indeed a limitation of Firestore, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations):

> **Limitations**
>
> Note the following limitations for in and array-contains-any:
>
> - in and array-contains-any support up to 10 comparison values.
> - *You can use only one in or array-contains-any clause per query*. You can't use both in and array-contains-any in the same query.
> - You can combine array-contains with in but not with array-contains-any.

Comment: is there any alternative way to check like i have two ids. uid1 and uid2 and want to check exist both, either uid1 = "reciverId" or uid1 = "senderId" or uid2 = "reciverId" or uid2 = "senderId"

Comment: You're essentially trying to do an OR query here, which isn't possible at the moment. You'll have to execute two separate queries, and then merge the results in your application code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is not clear to me. I am getting the same error chaining multiple array-contains, but according to the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) "You can chain multiple equality operators (== or array-contains) methods to create more specific queries (logical AND)". What am I missing here?

Comment: You can chain equality operations with one `array-contains`, not with multiple. See the limits at the end (**which Renaud quotes in his answer**): "You can use at most one `array-contains` clause per query."

Comment: @Renaud: Combining `array-contains-any` and `in` is now possible, since it works similarly to the newly added support for OR clauses. Want to update your answer and quote: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations? (triggered from here btw: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76016975)

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the heads up, I've adapted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.messages_collection = this.afs.collection<ChatMessage>('messages',
  ref => ref.where('email', 'in', [this.user.email, this.receiver.email])
    .where('receiver_email', 'in', [this.user.email, this.receiver.email])
    .orderBy('timesent')
);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).