# Firestore Query query working in query builder, but not in code

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've built a query with the native Firestore Query Builder and everything works fine and as I hoped/expected. However, when writing the same query in my code, I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid query. You cannot use 'in' filters with 'array-contains-any' filters."

```
export const filteredCandidates = (skills, type) => {
  return query(profilesCollection, 
    where("professional.available", "==", true), 
    where("professional.skills", "array-contains-any", skills), 
    where("professional.type", "in", type), 
    orderBy("lastActive", "asc"), 
    limit(50)
  );
}
```

Error as seen in browser:

[image]

Functional query as built in Query Builder on Firestore Console:

[image]

Comment: see the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60474813/11131192. States "in" limitations up to 10

Comment: I've come across this statement, but am quite confused why the query builder would allow for "array-contains-any" && "in" to be used in one query, if this is in fact (still) not available / possible. So surely, the above screenshot is proof that it is in-fact possible, as the query runs just fine and the result is correct. Now, that said, I assume the Firebase Console uses the same code/API that is available to users and hence, what's possible using the query builder, should be possible elsewhere - correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely using an outdated SDK version, and combining `array-contains-any` and `in` only recently became possible with the addition of OR clauses (as this internally works quite similar to an OR clause).

I got the same error when I just tried a query like yours on version 9.15, and the error then disappeared when I upgraded to version 9.19.1 (the latest at the moment).

You can find my repro here, in case you want to have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-acain

Comment: Perfect! - That was it, indeed it looks like I was using an earlier version as well and have not have had access to this feature locally just yet - I've upgraded my packages and the querys now works like a charm. Much appreciated for your help!